# How to indicate an array range in Excel using formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to indicate a range of an array in rows and columns, but I don't want to have to type one by one, is there any way to indicate the array row and column using the formulas: "ROW ()" AND "COL () ?? because it is hard work to type the range manually, the matrix has to be of the type that is in the image. I tried to indicate the ranges and could not get the correct sequence of numbers, okay?

[image]

Comment: No, it's not possible. Please share your final objective and we might suggest a better workaround

Comment: is offset() the function your are looking for? I mean : `=offset(C11,rows(C11:C15),columns(C11:D15))` please have a try and share the outcome...

Comment: correction, it should be : `=offset(C11,0,0,rows(C11:C15),columns(C11:D11))`

Comment: I debugged your formula by pressing "F9" and the result gave {0 \ 0; 0 \ 0,0 0 \ 0,0 0 \ 0}, in case it was given the correct number sequence: {1 \ 2; 3 \ 4,5 \ 6,7 7 \ 8,9 9 \ 10}, e agora?

Comment: I need to debug the formula (F9) to give the sequence {1 \ 2; 3 \ 4; 5 \ 6; 7 \ 8; 9 \ 10}

Comment: I don't understand.. how does the number series relates to the highlighted C10:D15 range ? Btw, you mentioned "to indicate a range of an array in rows and columns" but you didn't mention what operation (index/match / sum/average/multiplication/search) you want to do to the selected C10:D11 range. Would you mind clarifying  ?  ( :

Comment: I want to return this matrix in the image, no matter what formula I use, when I press (F9) to debug the formula, I want it to bring me this matrix with this numeric sequence

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
{=ROW(C11:D15)+COLUMN(C11:D15)-(13-(ROW()-11))}
```

adjusted for the language base of your copy of Excel.

The difficulty for your desire is the hard-to-define-a-pattern for reducing the results of the row and column values you are adding. In the simple version shown in the picture, just subtracting 13, say, gives {1\2;2\3... instead of {1\2;3\4...

You need a reducing amount to subtract so you need to keep reducing the "13" by 1 for each row you carry the formula down. Subtracting the rising quantity `ROW()-11` does this.

Comment: His formula brought me: {3 \ 4; 4 \ 5; 5 \ 6; 6 \ 7; 7 \ 8}

Comment: I think I'll end up defining a helper table with the sequence numbers at the positions I want and then fetch it with the formula "Index ()" and pull the values ​​in the correct sequence. Because I want her to bring me the break when debugging the formula in (F9)